# Backtrace all paths possible from goal to the start point

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, graph

There is a representation of a graph `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` where the key value is a vertise and it has a list of other vertises where we can get. The map may be bigger and lists may be `n size`. Number 1 represents the starting vertise and the biggest key number in map represents a goal.

Is there a way to loop through and collect paths of all the combinations of paths available from goal to start?

Example:

```
{ 2=[1], 3=[1], 4=[1], 5=[4, 2], 6=[4], 7=[1], 8=[7, 2], 9=[7, 3, 8] }
```

the goal is 9 and start is 1, so the output `List<List<Integer>>` should look like this:

```
[ [9, 7, 1], [9, 3, 1], [9, 8, 7, 1], [9, 8, 2, 1] ]
```

or without including 1

```
[ [9, 7], [9, 3], [9, 8, 7], [9, 8, 2] ]
```

My approach takes only first element from the list

parentNodes is `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

```
List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> nodes = Collections.singletonList(goal);
while(nodes != null && nodes.size() > 0) {
        if (nodes.size() > 1) {
            if (nodes.get(0) != goal || nodes.get(1) != goal) {
                shortestPath.add(nodes.get(0));
                System.out.println(shortestPath);
            }
        } else {
            path.add(nodes.get(0));
        }
        nodes = parentNodes.get(nodes.get(0));

    }
    Collections.reverse(path);
```

and the output is `List<Integer>` `[9, 7]` or reverse `[7, 9]` which is one of the shortest paths

Comment: Please attach the code you wrote trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your goal is achievable by dfs from largest vertex. You need to store the path and not visit any vertex, that already in the path. Detailed explanation [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/).
You just need to change `ArrayList<Integer>[] adjList;` to the `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> adjList;`